# Turn over a byte[] from Method A to Method B

Tags: c#, byte, arrays

I have two methods, `prepareData()` and `sendData()`:

```
    private void prepareData(string longFileName, string shortFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortFileName);
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    private void sendData(string clientIP, int clientPort, byte[] clientData)
    {
            TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(clientIP, clientPort);
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.GetLength(0));
            networkStream.Close();
            clientSocket.Close();
    }
```

`prepareData()` is called when the program is loaded; this is a heavy task.

`sendData()` is called every few seconds and should send the `byte[] clientData` from `prepareData()`.

How do I get `byte[]` from the first method to the second?

Comment: What `byte[]` is `sendData` sending?

Comment: don't get it. are you saying you want senddata to send the byte array created then thrown away in preparedata? or preparedata to call senddata, or something else entirely.

Comment: So you are storing the clientData in a local variable at program start to send it every few seconds, but where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the byte array clientData ist Empty when i want to send it in sendData... it doesn't has the Value of the byte[] clientData in the prepareData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As have already been stated, the problem is that you're storing clientData in a local variable that is simply thrown away when you exit prepareData. Your clientData must either be stored in a class variable, or returned from prepareData. Try doing something like this:

```
private byte[] prepareData(string longFileName, string shortFileName)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortFileName);
        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);
        byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
        fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
        fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
        return clientData;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}

private void sendData(string clientIP, int clientPort, byte[] clientData)
{
    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(clientIP, clientPort);
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    networkStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.GetLength(0));
    networkStream.Close();
    clientSocket.Close();
}
```

If you do it like this you don't need a timer for the sendData method call; just call it when prepareData has finished, like this:

```
    var clientData = prepareData("longFileName", "shortFileName");
    sendData(clientData);
```

OR

If prepareData really is a heavy task, you should get some threads going and read file blocks in one thread, use a ConcurrentQueue (as suggested by @dweeberly) to store them in, and another thread to call sendData.

Comment: Btw, this is the Producer-Consumer pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure what the problem is, but here is how I would solve your problem:

Add this using-directive

```
using System.Timers;
```

and in your Class with the prepareData and sendData-Method add a Timer as a field:

```
private Timer scheduler;
```

Add a StartSending-Method:

```
private void StartSending(byte[] clientData) {
    double interval = 2000; // 2000ms = 2s
    scheduler = new Timer(interval);
    scheduler.Elapsed += (sender, e) => {
        sendData("someIp", 123, clientData);
    };
    scheduler.Start();
}
```

Call this method as soon as your clientData is ready. 
Please clarify your problem if that doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to share data between two methods of your class in a time independent fashion.  You need to create a class global structure, based on your example something like:

```
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> clientData = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>()
```

Enqueue the data in your prepareData method and TryDequeue the data in sendData

Comment: This is a great Idea...but:

Comment: Here is my Code for Prepare Data: ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> clientDataQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
                clientDataQueue.Enqueue(clientData);

Comment: And for SendData         private void sendData(string clientIP, int clientPort, ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> clientDataQueue)
        {
                byte[] clientData;
                clientDataQueue.TryDequeue(out clientData);

Comment: But it didn't work... if he wants to write the client Data in the networkstream he throw out the exception

Comment: You don't need to pass the queue around.  The point of the queue being concurrent is so you can use it as a global variable.  What exception is being thrown.